# Why session scope bean is the same for different mock session in tests

Tags: java, spring, session, testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to test session scoped bean in Spring-boot but i've encountered problem.
I've created two MockHttpSession and try to inject them into controller method, which then will add to them scoped bean. If i run application those beans are different in each scope, but when i try to test it, the object is the same. Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ObserverSessionScopedIT {

@Autowired
private
ObserverController controller;

@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void sessionScope() throws Exception {

    MockHttpSession sessionFirst = new MockHttpSession();
    MockHttpSession sessionSecond = new MockHttpSession();

    sessionFirst.changeSessionId();
    sessionSecond.changeSessionId();

    controller.startObserving(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath(), sessionFirst);
    controller.startObserving(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath(), sessionSecond);

    Subscriptions subscriptionsFirst = (Subscriptions) sessionFirst.getAttribute("Subscriptions");
    Subscriptions subscriptionsSecond = (Subscriptions) sessionSecond.getAttribute("Subscriptions");

    Assertions.assertThat(subscriptionsFirst).isNotSameAs(subscriptionsSecond);

}
```

and here is how i menage it in controller:

```
private static final String SUBSCRIPTION = "Subscriptions";
(...)

@Autowired
private Subscriptions subscriptions;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> startObserving(@RequestBody String path, HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
     (...)
    httpSession.setAttribute(SUBSCRIPTION, subscriptions);
     (...)
    }
```

and this is definition of Subscriptions object:

```
@Service
@SessionScope
public class Subscriptions implements AutoCloseable{
```

Why i have two different objects while application works, but in test it's the same reference? I think it might be connected to context in test, but can i run tests with main application context?

Comment: Which actually works as it should work... You are getting a proxy which in turn delegates to a different (the actually scoped) object. You are basically comparing the proxies with each other which will always be the same.

Comment: But why when i'm using getAttribute("Subscriptions") in controller in actual application  it is different object for each session?

Comment: It isn't... It is a proxy... The proxy eventually delegates to the actual object. Could be that the hash is different due to serialization/deserialization but it still is a proxy and not the actual session scoped object... Check all of your attributes and you will see that there is another attribute as well (also you shouldn't be storing that in the session in the first place as it already is session scoped).

Comment: you think about "scopedTarget.<object>" attribute? But in that case could the Subscriptions is a proxy and scopedTarget is actual sessions object? And maybe you can point me to place where i can read about proxies in Spring? I think i don't have enough knowledge to fully understand this topic

Comment: That is basically what I'm trying to explain in the last 2 comments... If you want to know how the scopes work check the sources of `SessionScope` and see what happens in there and how the `ScopedProxyCreator` works.